# Join Two Tables Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called run:

| Scenario | Date | System | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Proj1 | 07-01 | A | PASS |
| Proj1 | 07-01 | B | PASS |
| Proj1 | 07-01 | C | PASS |
| Proj1 | 07-01 | D | PASS |
| Proj1 | 07-02 | A | FAIL |
| Proj1 | 07-02 | B | FAIL |
| Proj1 | 07-02 | C | FAIL |
| Proj1 | 07-02 | D | FAIL |

I have another table called mapping:

| Scenario | System | Priority |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Proj1 | A | 2 |
| Proj1 | B | 3 |
| Proj1 | C | 1 |
| Proj1 | D | 4 |

I want to join them to create a table that looks like this:

| Scenario | Date | System | Result | Priority |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Proj1 | 07-01 | A | PASS | 2 |
| Proj1 | 07-01 | B | PASS | 3 |
| Proj1 | 07-01 | C | PASS | 1 |
| Proj1 | 07-01 | D | PASS | 4 |
| Proj1 | 07-02 | A | FAIL | 2 |
| Proj1 | 07-02 | B | FAIL | 3 |
| Proj1 | 07-02 | C | FAIL | 1 |
| Proj1 | 07-02 | D | FAIL | 4 |

Does anyone know how I can achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You do a simple `INNER JOIN` on `Scenario` and `System`.

Comment: Can you share your best coding attempt at this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just `JOIN` your tables on equality of `Scenario` and `System` values in both tables.

```
SELECT
    r.*,
    m.Priority
FROM run r
JOIN mapping m USING (Scenario, System)
```